# From table with points to table with polygons

Tags: mysql

I have a table POINTS like the following:

```
POINTS
--------------------
ID_POINT     INT PK
COORD        POINT
POSITION     INT
ID_POLYGON   INT
```

With the following content

```
ID_POINT  COORD           POSITION     ID_POLYGON
---------------------------------------------------
1         POINT(1, 1)     1            1
2         POINT(2, 1)     2            1   
3         POINT(2, 2)     3            1
4         POINT(0, 0)     1            2
5         POINT(1, 0)     2            2
6         POINT(1, 1)     3            2
7         POINT(0, 1)     4            2
```

I need to extract with a query if possible the following resultset

```
ID_POLYGON           BORDERS
----------------------------------------------------
1                    POLYGON((1 1, 2 1, 2 2))
2                    POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1))
```

Somebody has solved a similar problem?

Note: the order of points is defined by the column position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is `GROUP_CONCAT`, i.e. something like

```
SELECT ID_POLYGON, GROUP_CONCAT(COORD ORDER BY POSITION ASC)
FROM POINTS
GROUP BY ID_POLYGON
```

For more on `GROUP_CONCAT` see the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT grants that the order of points is the order defined by the column position?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I've modified the query to order by position.